# Hide the file path and (library home) in IntelliJ IDEA 12

Tags: intellij-idea

I want the "file path" and the "(library home)" from the Project Tool window to be hidden.
See image below:

http://postimg.org/image/rscahvqn7/

Comment: Why would you want to do that? It seems very unlikely that there is such an option.

Comment: Simply because i don't like how it looks and i find it useless since there are other ways to find out the file path when needed.

Comment: Write a plugin to customize the project pane. But that's a lot of work... is it really worth it?

Comment: If that is the only option available then i may try.

Comment: nice! good luck. adding intellij-plugin tag to your question...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hope this will help though its quite late, in Idea 13, there is a drop down on the project tab, select and choose project files.

Comment: Whilst this does hide the file path and library home from each title, the file path becomes an extra heirarchical element under the title unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

just in case anyone comes cross this question you can add the following to you custom properties

```
project.tree.structure.show.url=false
ide.tree.horizontal.default.autoscrolling=false
```

found this on [you track](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-126014/Ability-to-hide-path-in-the-project-view#focus=Comments-27-3222305.0-0)